# no me funciona fonawesome en Angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome

Mi version de Angular CLI: 10.1.3 Node: 14.13.0

lo instale de la siguiente forma:

**npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free**

y archivo **angular.json**:

```js
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
                "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"          
            ],
            "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
```

despues en mi **html**

```html
  <div>
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
  </div>
```

pero no se ve ningun icono!

Comment: Ves algo en consola del navegador cuando cargas ese html? Algún error 404, algún mensaje, etc?

Comment: ningun error me sale!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No me funcionaba porque habia puesto las **rutas de los archivos** de **fontawesome** en el **"styles[]" y "scripts[]"** de **"test":{}** que estan abajo de todo en el **angular.json**. Se deben poner en los **"styles[]" y "scripts[]"** de **"build":{}** que estan al principio. De esta forma:

```js
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```